# What is the difference between the Semaphore of an OS and the Semaphore given by Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In OS a `Semaphore` is a basic synchronization pattern. So for concurrency we either use a `Semaphore` or a `Mutex`.

However, in Java for concurrency I have read in the book `Concurrent Programming in Java by Doug Lea` that the basic synchronization pattern is a `Monitor` (`Lock and WaitSet`)implemented for every object. It is only in Java 5 that `Semaphores` were added (along with `Locks` and other concurrency classes).

So how is this `Semaphore` different from the one provided by the OS(like the `Semaphore` of `PThread` library)?

Does java use OS Semaphore for implementing its Object Monitors?

Comment: I used semaphoresin C and Java, they're basically the same (as you can see by checking the javadoc). I dont think java uses OS semaphores http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.java

Comment: A monitor is essentially a mutex.

Comment: @for3st I have seen the Java code of `Semaphore`, what I wanted to ask is why was there a need for `Semaphore` later when they already had a monitor? And isn't `Monitor` used for the purpose that we wouldn't have to use a `Semaphore`? I read [this](https://blog.feabhas.com/2009/09/mutex-vs-semaphores-%E2%80%93-part-1-semaphores/) and it confused me more.

Comment: Java 5 was released September 2004, so it's merely a decade old. If you look further, the entire [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package was added in Java 5. The why is pretty simple, it is more efficient then the older `Monitor` style of locking.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch was efficiency the only reason for creating the `Semaphores`? Also, (for e.g. as the user threads are mapped to kernel threads) are Java Semaphores finally mapped to PThread or SystemV Semaphores?

Comment: @yadav_vi You'd have to ask Sun/Oracle if you want underlying root causes(s). That's also when they added `java.nio` and you could read through the old [1.5 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/relnotes-139183.html).

Comment: There are a half-dozen different, reasonably standard synchronization primitives.  Semaphore is one.  You could start a war over which one is "best".

Comment: If your question you wish to ask is different from what is in your question, I suggest you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27043567/edit) so that it asks the question you want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between a pthreads and Java lock is that the Java counterpart is **[reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing))**. This means that in Java it won't deadlock if you acquire the same lock that is already acquired (note that pthreads might have reentrant implementations as well).

Note that the modern implementation of Java `Semaphore` class (and other classes from `java.util.concurrent` package) uses directly CPU instructions such as [Compare-and-Swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) not a system call provided by the OS (or similar instructions if the hardware does not support it).

Comment: Is there a mapping in the JIT that goes directly to those "compare and swap" instructions on the CPU?  Does every CPU have "compare and swap" instructions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Before asking how does JDK do/is there, take a look at the source yourself (e.g. AtomicInteger.compareAndSet()). Then you can answer the first of your questions yourself, and the second becomes kind of superflous.

Comment: @Durandal: You're kidding, right?  m3th0dman is claiming to be an expert here... why would I go poring through source code I know nothing about, when I've got an expert right here I can ask a simple question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey there is a Unsafe class hidden in the JRE that has native calls that do the various atomic operations on fields. It is not unthinkable that the JIT can detect and optimize them.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: I asked the question because "uses directly CPU instructions" seems to go against the grain of what a JIT is supposed to do (i.e. *provide platform independence.*)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually the JIT compiles to the specific platform, the JVM provides the platform independence (and provides the JIT). It would be pretty easy to detect calls to `Unsafe.CompareAndSwapInt` and inline the actual machine code (or simulated equivalent code).

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I'm definetly *not kidding*; if a piece of software comes with a manual (in that case the source, including javadoc and comments which *are* a kind of manual), why would you *not* look at it? Its an analog of saying by default "The manual is too complicated, someone do the thinking for me" - before one even had a look at it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually you are right; apparently ARM does not have a CAS but similar functionality can be achieved. The other architectures that have a JVM (HotSpot) have CAS instruction and here it's pretty obvious the JVM uses it since probably is the most efficient. And I'm not an expert on the field (I didn't knew you have to be an expert to post an answer on SO, but I'll ask a question on meta not to make such mistakes again).

Comment: @Durandal: Frankly I'm getting a bit tired of the "what have you tried" mentality here.  Reading a user guide is one thing, wading through the source code of the Java Runtime Environment is quite another.  Most Java programmers shouldn't be expected to do that under ordinary conditions, and I have the right to question an assertion in someone's answer that I don't believe to be correct, even if I haven't read the JRE source code.

Comment: I went till `Unsafe.CompareAndSwapInt` but couldn't go any further as I don't understand the Java-JNI-C part. I have a doubt that how would java be able to bypass the OS directly to execute CAS instructions. Isn't everything supposed to go **through** the OS to the CPU instructions? (My knowledge of OS is pretty basic).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Completely understandable, but see the other side too - there is a steady increase of questions just "using" SO as a way of avoiding (personal) effort. Naturally SO users adapt to the environment, this attitude did not come to be without a cause. As for "most java programmers shouldn't be expected to...", since you asked about "how" internals, not simply how to use an API, I'd say yes one can expect that level of effort for that kind of question. If you just doubt correctness, you can always ask directly for a credible source of the information

Comment: And to at least attempt to answer the original question, this article (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp11234/) states they do use hardware instructions (it is by Brian Goetz, whom I consider a credible source). And do all CPU's have these instructions? No of course not (what would a microcontroller need them for?), but I bet all major ISA's have them. I know x86/x64 have them, PPC and ARM do have them. A multi-core CPU without would be very hard and inefficient to program without.

Comment: Note that a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) is a re-entrant lock by definition, and the OP asked about comparisons between the Java `Semaphore` and other *semaphores*, not other *non-semaphore locks*.

Comment: @DanGetz yes, I read the the [paper](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp11234/) mentioned above and have understood little. It would be great if someone posted a consolidated answer.

Comment: @DanGetz As I understood the problem the question is: the difference between basic synchronization mechanism provided by OS (PThreads) and the basic synchronization mechanism provided Java.

Answer (score 0):

> It is only in Java 5 that Semaphores were added...

Semaphore is a very old concept.  There's lots of old code and old algorithms out there that use semaphores.  If you wanted to port some of that old code to Java, you could use java.util.concurrent.Semaphore instead of writing your own.

I'm just guessing here, but I'd bet that's the main reason they added `Semaphore` to the library.